# Trouble loading external resources in iOS (not a whitelisting issue)

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

I have a Cordova app that runs the jQuery mobile framework and loads pages and their scripts/styles/images (on demand) from a remote site via ajax. This all works perfectly in Android.

When loading the same app in xcode + iOS sim, images are refusing to show, `$.mobile.base` is `undefined`, and appending CSS `<link>`s to the `<head>` fails. I have attached to the `pageload` event so that resources referenced in the `<head>` of ajax-fetched pages are manually added because jQm only pays attention to the `<body>` by default. I doubt it's a whitelist issue since I added the domain to the external hosts, and the pages themselves load as do scripts fetched with `$.ajax`. Everything is from the same domain.

The version on Cordova is 1.7.

Does anyone have a clue as to why the images and CSS won't load?

Comment: can you post some code that would be easier to test and confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in jQuery mobile, specifically `$.mobile.path.get()`. I submitted [the issue on github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4633).